# How to split array and only save specific value into database? Laravel with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a question. I need to save array into database but I need to divide it first and only save specific value. I am using Ajax and pass the data to controller.

ps: the array set can be more than 1 so each set need to split and store based on columns inside DB.

my javascript that contain Ajax:

```js
Hotspot.prototype.saveData = function (data) {
        if (!data.length) {
            return;
        }

        // Get previous data
        var raw_data = localStorage.getItem(this.config.LS_Variable);

        var hotspots = [];

        if (raw_data) {
            hotspots = JSON.parse(raw_data);
        }
    
        // Append to previous data
        $.each(data, function (index, node) {
            hotspots.push(node);
        });
        console.log(hotspots);

        // var field=JSON.stringify(hotspots).split(',');
        this.data=data;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/store",
            dataType:'json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data:{
                Title: JSON.stringify(hotspots),
                Message: JSON.stringify(hotspots),
                x: JSON.stringify(hotspots), 
                y: JSON.stringify(hotspots),
            },
            success: function(data){

                console.log(data,d);
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            },
            
        });

        localStorage.setItem(this.config.LS_Variable, JSON.stringify(hotspots));

        this.element.trigger('afterSave.hotspot', [null, hotspots]);
    };
```

Controller:

```
public function storePin(Request $request)
    {
       request()->validate([
           'Title' => 'required',
            'Message'  => 'required',
            'x'=> 'required',
            'y'=>'required',
       ]);

           dd($request);
             if ($request->all())
             {
                 $pin = new Pin();
                 $pin->Title=json_encode($request->input('Title'));
                 $pin->Message= json_encode($request->input('Message'));
                 $pin->x = json_encode($request->input('x'));
                 $pin->y =json_encode($request->input('y'));

                 $pin->save();
                //  return response()->json_encode($request);

             }

    }
```

example output:

```
Title: [{"x":58.333333333333336,"y":90.54545454545455,"Title":"hi","Message":"hi"}]
Message: [{"x":58.333333333333336,"y":90.54545454545455,"Title":"hi","Message":"hi"}]
x: [{"x":58.333333333333336,"y":90.54545454545455,"Title":"hi","Message":"hi"}]
y: [{"x":58.333333333333336,"y":90.54545454545455,"Title":"hi","Message":"hi"}]
```

based on this I only want that it only store:

```
Title:only save title
Message:save message
x:save x
y save y
```

Comment: if u guys want to grasp the basic of my project click this link and try the demo                        https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Editable-Hotspots-On-Any-Elements/admin-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

Just pass in the whole array of hotspots like:

```js
data: hotspots,
```

Then in your model do any formatting and insert many:

```php
// some formatting to create data array
$data = [];
foreach($hotspots as $hotspot){
    $data[] = [
        'Title' => $hotspot['Title'],
        'Message'  => $hotspot['Message'],
        'x' => $hotspot['x'],
        'y' => $hotspot['y'],
    ];
}

Pin::insert($data);
```

Comment: This answer seems to make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be parsing of `data` to `hotspots`. This method is iterating over each entry of `data`, then assigning the full node.

```
$.each(data, function(index, node) {
  hotspots.push(node);
});
```

Each property definition is using the full `hotspots` object, as opposed to one property.

```
data: {
  Title: JSON.stringify(hotspots),
  Message: JSON.stringify(hotspots),
  x: JSON.stringify(hotspots),
  y: JSON.stringify(hotspots),
},
```

You probably need to do something like this:

```
{
  Title: hotspots[0].Title,
  Message: hotspots[0].Message,
  x: hotspots[0].x,
  y: hotspots[0].y,
}
```

Even still, this solution is missing some important information. For example, `hotspots` should be an array of `hotspot` objects...how do you know which one you are going to send for the single request?

Comment: i already tried it work...but its only take 1 set of array......so the other set is not saved like here i have 3 set of array 0: {x: 44.135802469135804, y: 93.63636363636364, Title: "1", Message: "1"}
1: {x: 32.03703703703704, y: 87.45454545454545, Title: "2", Message: "2"}
2: {x: 67.5925925925926, y: 82.9090909090909, Title: "3", Message: "3"} but its only save the first array